# How to update multiple records in a table Using the Linq for Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am currently facing a problem of updating multiple records in a database. I want to update the list of items created by the users when a receipt is created as the user is making the payment.

This is my API method to update them.

```cs
[HttpPut("update-items")]
public ActionResult UpdateListOfItems(IEnumerable<ItemUpdateDTO> itemUpdateDTOs)
{
    if(itemUpdateDTOs == null)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    var items = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Item>>(itemUpdateDTOs);
    _repository.UpdateRangeItem(items);

    return Ok("Updated items!");
}
```

Here is my DTO for Item Update

```cs
public class ItemUpdateDTO
{
    [Required]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public FishUpdateDTO Fish { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ReceiptUpdateDTO Receipt { get; set; }
}
```

This is the entity model for the table "Item"

```cs
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int FishID { get; set; }
    public Fish Fish { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int QuantityOrdered { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public float TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public Receipt Receipt { get; set; }
    public User Customer { get; set; }
}
```

This is the entity model for "Categories"

```cs
public class FishCategory
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Fish> Fish { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the repository method.

```cs
public void UpdateRangeItem(IEnumerable<Item> items)
{
    _databaseContext.Items.UpdateRange(items);
    _databaseContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Here is the item table:

[image]

and the receipt table:

[image]

I am trying to update the item table with the id of receipt as the foreign key in item table. However, I get an error:

> The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Fishes_Categories_CategoryID". The conflict occurred in database "EFishing", table "dbo.Categories", column 'ID'.

Currently, I'm using the `DatabaseContext` method called `UpdateRange()` to update a range of rows within one call to the database.

Any solutions will do. Thanks

Comment: You have an SQL Server error that says the data you send to the Fish table is invalid. Can you add the definition of the Fish table, as well as the data you're sending as `itemUpdateDTOs`?

Comment: Also, please note that the language snippet feature is only meant for JS/HTML and not for all languages.

Comment: Why didn't you look at the data you send (`items`)? It's pretty clear that you're trying to save a `CategoryID` that doesn't exist in table `Category`. That's all we can tell you, but that's just rephrasing the exception message.

Comment: @GertArnold thanks for rephrasing the exception message but funny enough there's data in the table "Category".

Comment: Well, there can be millions of rows there. You're sending a non-existing FK value and you don't seem to even look at where that value is in `items`. *You* have to do this, we can't see what's in there, let alone solve it.

Comment: @GertArnold I get your point. I managed to solve it by only passing the "categoryId" only and not another inner class of type "Category".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I know it's late but here's my answer which solved my problem.

Since the issue was on this ->

> The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Fishes_Categories_CategoryID". The conflict occurred in database "EFishing", table "dbo.Categories", column 'ID'.

It was due to the fact that the particular CategoryID didn't exists in my Categories table, hence throwing that error. The error produced by the compiler may not contain useful message but checking your data which you post (maybe using Postman), do check if the related data that your entity is having a relationship with exists or not.

For example, if I have

Category Table
| CategoryID | Category |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1| Salt Water|
| 2| Fresh Water|

Here is Fish table
| Fish ID| Name| CategoryID|
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| 1| Salmon| 1|
But in Postman or which ever software you use to post data to the API, if you post a "Fish" data to the Fish table with the "CategoryID" of 3, the error will occured and will print as of the above. So do make sure, that you have a "CategoryID: 3" exists in the Category table.

Credits to @AFract. His answer in some error prone possibilities is above my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to multiple updates of Items at once.

As SQL server tells you, it's related to Fish, and categories.

Probably one or more of your Items have a Fish on it, this fish points to a FishCategory that doesn't exist, hence the Foreign Key violation.

A foreign key not set but defined as not nullable will take the value "0" (integer's default) and, if your ids start from 1 fail in the same way. Maybe a nullable FK may help (if it's meaningful in terms of data).

Verify your database structure and the data you are attempting to save : Fish property of item, and Category of Fish.